# Is there a way to retrieve an attachment from a Sharepoint list via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: json, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Sharepoint list that contains a column for an attachment, which is an image file. When retrieving information on the list item that has an attachment, it has a field `attachment: true`

However, there is no mention of Sharepoint list attachments on the Microsoft Graph documentation. It only mentions mail, calendar and group attachments, although it doesn't say anything about retrieving the attached file.

Is there a way for me to retrieve that file?

Comment: Hi Currently Graph not support retrieving attachments. You can use the Rest API to get the attachments of the list item. <SiteURL>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/